# opening a silverlight childWindow overlay on the viewport of the browser

Tags: silverlight

I would like place a silverlight contol on an HTML page --- something about the size of a typical calendar control. However when the user selects a day on the control a bigger canvas opens up on top of the containing page --- something like a modal dialog box that you might find with the AJAX.

I'm wondering if this is even possible with Silverlight, or is the silverlight content limited in size to the DIV element on the host page?

UPDATE: after doing some poking around, I think the answer will involve using the ChildWindow control introduced with Silverlight 3.  However I'm still at a loss how to have the ChildWindow display ontop of the existing content

Answer (score 1):

I know one way, you will need javascript event on the page itself to expand a silverlight object to fit the whole page then build you silverlight event accordingly.